# OWL Pagination on image slider

Tags: html, wordpress, css, owl-carousel

How can I move owl-pagination div on image slider without using position absolute and negative top?

this is my current css:

```
.owl-pagination{
    position: relative;
    top: -260px;
}
```

Comment: do provide more detail

Comment: in relation to what?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [css3 transforms](http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms):

```
.owl-pagination{
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-260px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that owl-pagination move up or down in base the width of another div... Thanks again!